# Periodic Function?

Tags: periodic-functions

What is the period of this function? And how do you come about your answer?

$$\epsilon_n(x)=\sum_{\mu=-\infty}^{+\infty}(x+\mu)^{-n}$$

I understand that $\epsilon_n(x+k)=\epsilon_n(x)$ (sort of)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. By the *change of index* $\nu=\mu\pm 1$ one gets
$$
\epsilon_n(x)=\sum_{\mu=-\infty}^{+\infty}(x+\mu)^{-n}=\sum_{\nu=-\infty}^{+\infty}(x\pm1+\nu)^{-n}=\epsilon_n(x\pm 1),
$$ one may prove the period is equal to $1$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this - when you say change the index: 
$\nu=\mu\pm1$ 

Wouldn't this result in: 
$$\epsilon_n(x)=\sum_{\mu=-\infty}^{+\infty} (x + \nu \pm 1)^{-n}=\epsilon_n(x\pm1)$$

Where does the $1$ go in your first substitution? (I am not very familiar with this topic so apologies if I am being extremely ignorant here)

Comment: @HughEntwistle Sure. This was a typo. Edited. Thanks.